# Android: clear activities stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activities:

**Activity1**, that should be opened once (first launch)
**Activity2**, the main screen.
After doing some things in **Activity1** on first launch, every next launch **Activity2** should be opened.
I kinda figured out how to do this, and it works perfectly, but when I press "back" button on my phone, **Activity1** suddenly appears.

So how can I fix it? Should I clear stack or what?

Here's my code:

**Activity1**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button but1;
    EditText input1;
    TextView error1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_page);

        if(getName("username")!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomePageLast.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        ListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void ListenerOnButton(){
        but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.welcome_page_button);
        input1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_input);
        error1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_error);

        but1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        if (input1.getText().toString().length() < 2){
                            error1.setText("Слишком короткое имя!");
                        }else {
                            error1.setText("");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomePageLast.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            setName("username", input1.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void setName(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getName(String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
}
```

**Activity2**:

```
public class WelcomePageLast extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView greetings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String greeting_message = getString(R.string.greetings_message) + prefs.getString("username", "") + "!";

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_page_last);

        greetings =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.greetings);
        greetings.setText(greeting_message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't send you back to last acitivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomePageLast.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
setName("username", input1.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` - Clears the activity stack. If you don't want to clear the activity stack. PLease don't use that flag then.

Comment: Oh, thanks, works perfectly!